# Node js console write percentage

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, line

I need to write in the same line with other lines going at the same time.

```
var i = 1;
write();
function write() {
    if (i == 6) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('-------------');
        process.stdout.write('Downloading ' + i + '% complete... \r');
        i++;
        write();
    }, 100);
}
```

What I get:

```
-------------
-------------% complete... 
-------------% complete... 
-------------% complete...  Downloading 5% complete...
```

What I need:

```
-------------
Downloading 5% complete...
-------------
-------------
-------------
-------------
```

I prefer to do this without any modules.

There are various topics here talking about this, but none explains how to do as I want.

I think I need to save the cursor position when I write the line the first time and then the next time I write, I have to move the cursor to the saved line right?

Comment: Couldn't help but notice `-------------` is `13` chars and `Downloading 5` is `13` chars, i.e. your `---`s are writing over the top of the `log` from the previous time around. (This is because `"\r"` is not the new line char you want ;) )

Comment: @PaulS. That would've made a great answer.

Comment: Thanks Paul S. with your answer now I understand how this works.

Answer (score 4):

```
process.stdout.write('Downloading ' + i + '% complete... \r');
```

The `\r` character means to return to the beginning of the current line.  You're looking for `\n`, which also jumps down a line.  Or just continue to use `console.log` as for your other line, which automatically appends a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of thing using the curses library in C/C++. 
There is a node equivalent called node-ncurses which might help you.

https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses